# Excel Counting Specific Order of Items in a Column

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning out there!

I have a spreadsheet with a column of something like the following (please omit the numbers, they're there to format the open, closed, not available cells):

1. OPEN
2. OPEN
3. not available
4. OPEN
5. CLOSED
6. OPEN
7. CLOSED
8. not available
9. CLOSED
10. not available
11. OPEN

I'm looking for a solution (VBA preferable) where it would count the amount of times the cells change in that column from OPEN to CLOSE to OPEN.  In this example, the correct amount of 'cycles' would be 2.  I'm not really sure how to incorporate a moving COUNT where it actively looks for a condition then after finding one, counts it, then moves below to continue looking.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Edit:

Thanks to Michael Moulsdale for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22560113/3446462)! I edited the code to look for a blank cell instead of END.  Here is the code:

```
PrivateSub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim VarCycles
Dim BooStart
Dim booClosed

VarCycles = 0
BooStart = False
booClosed = False

Range("B2").Select
While Selection.Value <> IsEmpty("B2")
    If Selection.Value = "OPEN" And BooStart = False Then
        BooStart = True
    End If
    If Selection.Value = "CLOSED" And BooStart = True Then
        BooStart = False
        VarCycles = VarCycles + 1
    End If
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Value = VarCycles
```

End Sub

Comment: I see only one pattern `Open->Closed->Open` (4->5->6). Why `the correct amount of 'cycles' would be 2`?

Comment: Post some code. Have you tried anything? what are your errors? or you just want someone do it for you?

Comment: SO 4->5->6 is 1 cycle and the second cycle is 6->7->11.  The same OPEN can being a 'cycle' and close a 'cycle'.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post and I didn't know to put down my own code.  I've been playing around with =COUNTIF(B:B,(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(Q1,B:B,0)+1="OPEN"))) where the OPEN, CLOSE list is in the B column and Q1=CLOSE.  I know I can swap that in the code but I've been switching things around to see if I can get something that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA I would do something like the following. It should be noted that I added an END as the last variable in your list and used this to test for the last value. But you could equally test for blank or some other mechanism that is appropriate for your situation

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    varCycles = 0
    booStart = False
    booClosed = False

    Range("B2").Select
    While Selection.Value <> "END"
        If Selection.Value = "OPEN" And booStart = False Then
            booStart = True
        End If
        If Selection.Value = "CLOSED" And booStart = True Then
            booStart = False
            varCycles = varCycles + 1
        End If
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Wend
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Value = varCycles
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with this function :

```
=IF(AND(A1="OPEN"; A2="CLOSED"; A3="OPEN"); 1; 0)
```

Put it in the first row and pull the cell to applied it to all the column. But in your example, I think there is only one "cycle", isn't it ?